# Google Maps Marker: Need option for 'Get Directions'

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps, map-directions

Rather straight forward question.

I have currently implemented the google map on my site. I have so far been able to edit what data is displayed on the marker and exactly how that data is styled.

I am stuck on one last point. I need to be able to give visitors the option to click 'Get Directions'. I have a link on the marker called "Directions". I would like for visitors to be able to click this it 'somehow' and provide them with directions. I'm not sure of the means or how this is accomplished. I've looked everywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have included a screen shot of my marker.

Screenshot of marker/map http://postimg.org/image/t5v5hy7yj/

Also, when answering, treat me as someone who knows only the basics of what was required to do this so far. Thanks!

EDIT *****

I have edited it so that when they hit the 'directions' link it takes the Google map search command and places inside it what I command it to from the mysql database. They would still need to click directions one more time at the now google result page to get directions. I need a more direct way of doing this! =)

```
  downloadUrl("genxml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var city = markers[i].getAttribute("city");
      var state = markers[i].getAttribute("state");
      var zip = markers[i].getAttribute("zip");
      var phone = markers[i].getAttribute("phone");
      var url = markers[i].getAttribute("url");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = 
      '<a href="' + url + '" target="blank">' + name + '</a>' +
      '</a><br/><br/>' + address +
      '<br>' + city + ' ' + state + ' ' + zip +
      '<br/>' + phone + 
      '<hr style="border: none; height: 1px; color: blue; background: grey;"/>' +
      '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q='+ address + ' ' + city + ' ' + state + ' ' + zip + '" target="blank"><u>Directions</u></a> ' + ' <a href="#"><u>Write a Review</u></a> ' + ' <a href="#"><u>more</u></a>' +
      '<hr style="border: none; height: 1px; color: blue; background: grey;"/>' +
      '<?php echo $ads ?>';
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
```

Comment: whats with the troll face?

Comment: is it something like this: http://www.christlivingchurch.com/home/directions.html#directions_table (I developed this site)

Comment: I'm not sure the method in which it's done is important. Not so much as the 'how'. I'm not even sure where to start. I have over 10,000 markers on my map. I need for visitors to be able to click a marker and somehow have an option to get directions to the address on the marker.

Comment: Your example would work I assume if it wold give directions for whatever marker was selected.

Comment: What would also work if when they clicked the Direction link it automatically searched google for the address. Maybe by pulling data out of the required fields and feeding it into a google search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the HTML string for the info window, add an `onclick` parameter that calls a javascript function like this: `showDirections(" + address + "," + city + "," + state + "," + ")`

This link should help you create the function to show directions:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple

Comment: Not sure this will work. I need them to click markers that are on my map and get directions from THOSE markers.

Comment: If you give me a while, I can probably get some code that will do that. I think there is a way, but it would help if you could give me a code sample.

Comment: Yeah that'd be awesome. Give me a few and i'll post it. Trying one last thing.

Comment: I have updated my post with the code. And with the way that I have set it up to search google maps on request. This will not suffice either tho. It's closer however.

Comment: Thank you for the code sample! I will probably be able to edit my answer tomorrow.

Comment: Could you add all the Javascript including the initialize() function for the map?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks tho. I've accepted your answer. TY! =)

Comment: Ok, great! Thanks for accepting my answer. I might add the code anyway, for other people viewing this question.